# What is the complexity of the code below?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Can anybody help me to find out the complexity of the following code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
//finding the factorial value
int fact(int n)
{
    return (n<=1)?1 : n*fact(n-1);
}

int fun(char *str)
{
    int rank=1;
    int len=strlen(str);

    for (int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {    
        int count=0;
        //finding characters smaller than str[i]
        for(int j=i+1;str[j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            if(str[j]<str[i])
            count++;
        }

        len--;
        //finding the rank
        rank+=count*fact(len);
    }
    return rank;
}

int main()
{
    char str[]="string";
    cout<<endl<<fun(str);
    return 0;
}
```

I think it's O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

The factorial function is O(n) and fun is O(n^2) so, actually it is O(n^2) in total.

Comment: [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327244/complexity-of-recursive-factorial-program)             and fun is O(n^2) that's obvious from nested loops and in the outer loop the fact() is being called n times .So,at most it's O(n^2) where n is the length of string.

Comment: thnk u zan..can u explain me step by step how it is O(n^2)

Comment: First the main() calls fun() exactly once.And fun() takes a string of size n.So,all we need to find is the time complexity for fun() in terms of n and inside fun() we have two loops.first loop runs n times and second one n-1 times.so,in total n*(n-1) which is O(n^2) but inside fun() we call fact() n times and fact() is just O(2^log2(n)) = O(n).so in total it should be O(n^2)